# Recover the root system from a root lattice

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

I am new to Lie algebra and have a maybe naive question about root system.

If we have a root system $\Phi$ we can associate it with a lattice $\Lambda(\Phi)$. I want to know how to recover the $\Phi$ from $\Lambda(\Phi)$? In particular I want to know that for type ADE, is $\Phi$ just the vectors in $\Lambda$ with minimal norm?

---

**Edit**

I note that my original question does not make much sense because non-isomorphic root systems may give the same lattice, for example $A_1\times A_1$ and $B_2$. So let's only consider the case of type ADE.

Comment: What do you consider the root lattice to be? An abstract $\mathbb{Z}$-module, a subset of a Euclidean space, ...

Comment: @Joppy A subset of a Euclidean space, or equivalently, a $\mathbb Z$-module together with the inner product. Sorry for did not make myself clear, but I mentioned "minimal norm" so I assumed you could guess so :)

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/293756/27465

Comment: It is indeed true. The vectors in $\Lambda$ of minimal norm ($>0$) are usually normalized to have norm $\sqrt{2}$ and give you back precisely the root system $\Phi$ as it is proved case by case for type $\mathsf{ADE}$ in [the Wikipedia page on root systems][1]. 

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system

Comment: @user213008 That's very nice. But I didn't see the statement on the wiki page?

Comment: @Akatsuki It is not explicitly stated like this. But look under the section "Explicit construction of the irreducible root systems", read those subsection for type $\mathsf{ADE}$. Each time the root system is defined upon the root lattice by vectors of length $\sqrt{2}$. I think this proves all you need.

Comment: @user213008 Yes I think you are right. You can post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors in $\Lambda$ of minimal norm ($>0$) are usually normalized to have norm $\sqrt{2}$ and give you back precisely the root system $\Phi$ as it is proved case by case for type $\mathsf{ADE}$ in [the Wikipedia page on root systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system).

It is not explicitly stated like this. But look under the section "Explicit construction of the irreducible root systems", read those subsection for type $\mathsf{ADE}$. Each time the root system is defined upon the root lattice by vectors of length $\sqrt{2}$.

(These are the comments of mine above made into an answer.)

Comment: In the answer to this post on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293756/shortest-vectors-in-a-root-lattice , I give a reference where you can find a full proof of this statement in a more general setup.